# What does the phrase isn't/doesn't he/she just" originate?/

Tags: phrase-origin

As [The Machmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/isn-t-he-she-just-doesn-t-he-she-just) puts it this phrase is used for emphasis. For example:

> Person 1: Kate was angry with Mike for breaking her vase.
>
> Person 2: **Isn't she just**.

This phrase sounds so strange to my non-native ear. Why this phrase is used in the question form and the word *just* is there for?

Comment: Your example doesn't sound idiomatic to me, because Person 2 should obviously be saying ***Wasn't** she just.* In such contexts, ***just*** approximately means ***exactly, truly*** - Person 2 is wholeheartedly agreeing that Kate's emotional state was exactly as described *(**so** angry)*. In practice the usage tends to occur in contexts where the preceding utterance includes a relevant adjective/adverb: *Kate was **really / very** angry*, where the word ***just*** more explicitly refers to agreement that *she **truly was exactly** that angry*.